# Why have I lost my ability to close a question?

Tags: discussion, support, closing, privileges

It's not that I like to close questions, and indeed I haven't yet, just wondering why.
I earned the privilege some days ago, when I gained a bunch of points in all SE sites, but then, as it turns out, the "close" button disappeared.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At [250 reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes), you earn the privilege to view and cast close/re-open votes on *your own questions*. The ability to [vote to close/re-open others' questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) is earned at 3000 reputation here.

Comment: Oh dear, I got this muddled. Thank you.